# javascript for loop is not incrementing

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am trying to using a for loop for trying to validate the input of the user and this is the code i got.

```
function Valid() {
  objfieldid = ["userMail", "userCont"]
  objboxid = ["cancelMail", "cancelCont"]
  return objfieldid.every(callnonvalid)
}
function callnonvalid(id) {
  var valid = false
  var objlength = objfieldid.length
  objlength--;
  for (var i = objlength; i >= 0; i--){
    var cobj = document.getElementById(objboxid[i]).checked;
    if (document.getElementById(id).value != "" ){
      var obj = document.getElementById(id).value;
    } else if (cobj == true) {
      alert(i); //return 1, 1
      return true
    } else {
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, in the code, the for loop is running twice. but the i variable is left unchanged. Why would this happen?

btw, I did read different material about closure and i am sure there didnt got a closure problem

EDIT:guys please note that i did noticed the array is zero based, and i did minus the objlength by one.

Comment: Please fix the code indentation

Comment: I just edited the question, waiting for peer review

Comment: What do you mean but "i variable is left unchanged"? It is decremented by one each cycle.

Comment: Check the console. There will be an error; Hint: the index of an array is zero-based

Comment: Well by what i mean i variable is left unchanged, i meant that is not decremented by one each cycle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mistakes were found after checking the code carefully. The Mistake that I made was that I should not use the return for the out since that would stop the function from working, however that `array.every` Called the function twice which make the i not decreasing

Answer (score 0):

Because the array `objboxid[]` has only two elements, the first time through your loop `objboxid[2]` will be attempting to fetch an array index that is out-of-bounds.

You probably meant something like:

```
for (var i = objlength; i > 0; i--){
  var cobj = document.getElementById(objboxid[i-1]).checked;
```

or perhaps

```
for (var i = objlength-1; i >= 0; i--){
  var cobj = document.getElementById(objboxid[i]).checked;
```

Comment: What would happen if we use the `objboxid[i - 1]`, but instead of `for (var i = objlength; i >= 0; i--){`, we would change the `>=` to `>`? That way, the value of `i=0` is never reached, and no negative index is ever referenced.

Comment: The first time the loop is running objboxid[1], note that there is a decrement for objlength

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. Meant to update for loop on first example but forgot. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're decrementing in your loop, because the performance gain would be infinitesimally small (it may even be slower, e.g. in Chrome/V8) and working in reverse order can get confusing further down the line, but that's your choice and I don't know enough about what you're doing to judge.

Either way, I don't think you'd want to decrement `objlength` before the loop begins as you are doing now. The whole point of a loop is to handle the incrementing/decrementing in the condition statement of the loop.

You would only decrement manually like that if you were going to move your `if/else if/else` statement into a closed over function and execute it recursively, decrementing the `objlength` from within the closure. Which would work, but it's unnecessarily complicated for what you're doing and you would gain nothing for rewriting the whole thing.

So, sticking with the looping approach, perhaps try either of these:

```
function Valid() {
  objfieldid = ["userMail", "userCont"];
  objboxid = ["cancelMail", "cancelCont"];
  return objfieldid.every(callnonvalid);
}

function callnonvalid(id) {
  var valid = false;
  var objlength = objfieldid.length;

  for(var i = 0; i < objlength; i++){
    var cobj = document.getElementById(objboxid[i]).checked;
    if (document.getElementById(id).value != "" ){
      var obj = document.getElementById(id).value;
    } else if (cobj == true) {
      alert(i); 
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

or, if you want to decrement, use `while` instead of `for`:

```
function Valid() {
  objfieldid = ["userMail", "userCont"];
  objboxid = ["cancelMail", "cancelCont"];
  return objfieldid.every(callnonvalid);
}

function callnonvalid(id) {
  var valid = false;
  var i = objfieldid.length;

  while(i--){
    var cobj = document.getElementById(objboxid[i]).checked;
    if (document.getElementById(id).value != "" ){
      var obj = document.getElementById(id).value;
    } else if (cobj == true) {
      alert(i);
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```